# Shell script detecting errors from command called by script

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, redirection, pipe

I am calling applications from my shell script, which performs a number of important steps in sequence, one step being below:

```
for database in $( 
        echo 'show databases;' | 
        mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/sqlbackup/my.cnf \
              -e 'show databases' -s --skip-column-names|
        grep -vi information_schema )
do
  echo $database
done
exit 0
```

I am able to be able to log the output to the screen, that I am doing via the echo function.

My question is what would happen if an application (any command line called from the script), cannot connect and chucked an error such as:

```
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`?
```

Are errors reported in a separate environment variable outside the string output, if so how can I detect this? How would one change the path the script takes depending on success or failure?

I am a .Net programmer and the best analogy i can make is where an exception is thrown and handeled:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
  // log the reason here: echo "error running database command: " + e.Description
}
```

Is there something similar to the above but for borne/bash shell?

Comment: Read whole thing or only about redirection [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) and [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt). If none of that makes sense, you should probably check out [bash for beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) and [ABS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). Happy learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three main streams of data: input, output and error.

- Stdin is input
- Stdout is output
- Stderr is error

You can redirect the error messages by adding this `2>file.log` at the end of your command.

This will write errors to log file which in turn you could read with `tailf file.log` - in a separate screen if you will.

```
$( echo 'show databases;' | /usr/bin/mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/sqlbackup/my.cnf -e 'show databases' -s --skip-column-names 2>>file.log |grep -vi information_schema )
```

If you need more details take a look in here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about checking for error codes rather than just text to confirm an error has occured and take a different route in the script?

Comment: @g18c  You could use the `$?` to check for exit code of last command. See the example here: http://blog.yimingliu.com/2009/01/01/check-last-exit-status-code-in-bash-shell/